# Does type guard function affect the performance of the app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```js
const typeGuard = (param: any): param is SomeType => {
   return (
     !!param &&
     typeof param === "object" &&
     param.someProperty1 !== null &&
     param.someProperty2 === null
   )
}
```

If there is a type guard function like the code above and the function is executed more than 1000 times,

Does it affect the performace of the app??

(EDIT)

My app is React app and type guard function will be executed about 1400 times when data is fetched

Example code is

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const dataFetch = () => {
      fetch().then((response) => {
        // this part will be executed about 1400 times
        const newState = response.map((data: unknown) => {
          if (typeGuard(data)) {
            return { processedData };
          }
        });
        setData(newState);
      });
    };

    dataFetch();

    if (delay !== null) {
      const interval = setInterval(dataFetch, delay);

      return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
      };
    }
  }, [delay]);
```

Comment: I think in order for anyone to answer we'd need more information about the app (what else is it doing?  1000 times total?  per animation frame?) and the runtime environment, and what the alternative is (is it simply *not* executing the function?  Is it executing some other version of the same function?) Otherwise you're going to get people's opinions or very general answers.  Here's mine: don't worry about performance of non-loopy non-recursive functions like this until you actually start hitting performance problems somewhere, and then profile your app to find where the actual bottleneck is.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I edited my question. Please let me know if you want more information.

Comment: Ideally I'd be able to drop that into a standalone IDE and demo the issue myself; that is, it should be a [mre].  If I do that all I see are [errors](https://tsplay.dev/WJq1rm); do you have any way of demonstrating the issue or at least providing code that doesn't depend on undeclared/unimported/undefined values/types/libraries?

Comment: Oh, I didn't explain good enough. I just wanted to know if the type guard function had any impact on the performance of the react app. Not about errors or issues, just my Curiosity. Sorry to confuse you

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  But I can't even really imagine how the performance of your app would be affected if I don't know what it does, and so any example code should be a [mre].  If someone needs to know about React to answer, then you might want to add the `reactjs` tag. If someone *doesn't* need to know, then you should remove the dependency from the example and just show something that behaves similarly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since the body of your type guard is *actually being executed at runtime* - it does affect runtime performance.

How much does it affect it? Well, you could do your measurements, I could just propose to play with `console.time()` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/timeLog))